# Specialized inheritance of a templated class causes member function to return templated class type rather than inherited class type

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, inheritance, overloading

Assume I have a base class like this:

```
template<typename T>
class Base {
public:
    Base& operator()(const T& value) {
        this->value = value;
        return *this;
    }
    T value;
};
```

Now I want to inherit from this class to create type-specific classes

```
class InheritedFloat : public Base<float> {} inheritedFloat;
```

Now here I try to catch this inheritance in a functon:

```
void function(const InheritedFloat& inherited) {
    std::cout << inherited.value << '\n';
}
```

Calling this function like this works fine, of course:

```
int main() {
    function(inheritedFloat); //(inheritedFloat is a global instance)

    return 0;
}
```

But when I try to call it with the `operator()(const float& value){...}` member function, `function(const InheritedFloat& inherited){...}` doesn't see it as a `InheritedFloat`-Type but instead as a `Base<float>`-Type:

```
int main() {
    function(inheritedFloat(10.f)); //error

    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
Error   C2664   'void function(const InheritedFloat &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'Base<float>' to 'const InheritedFloat &'
```

So how can I make `operator()(const T& value){...}` return `InheritedFloat&` instead of `Base<float>&`?

---

To clearify further, this is just a simplified example (of course). I have dozens of inheritance cases. So I can't just template-specify `function()`

```
template<typename T>
void function(const Base<T>& inherited) {
    std::cout << inherited.value << '\n';
}
```

because each inheritance needs to be treated differently. Types will overlap, so there will be multiple `Base<std::size_t`> cases, for example.

The whole code:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class Base {
public:
    Base& operator()(const T& value) {
        this->value = value;
        return *this;
    }
    T value;
};

class InheritedFloat : public Base<float> {} inheritedFloat;


void function(const InheritedFloat& inherited) {
    std::cout << inherited.value << '\n';
}

int main() {
    function(inheritedFloat(10.f));

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for reading, I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can utilize [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) here. By supplying extra template parameter you can make base class function return a reference to a derived class:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename Derived, typename T>
class Base {
public:
    Derived & operator()(const T& value) {
        this->value = value;
        return *static_cast<Derived *>(this);
    }
    T value;
};

class InheritedFloat : public Base<InheritedFloat, float> {} inheritedFloat;


void function(const InheritedFloat& inherited) {
    std::cout << inherited.value << '\n';
}

int main() {
    function(inheritedFloat(10.f));

    return 0;
}
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/iwHzJqUw4nT3F4tg)

Comment: Yeah that's what I also tried, but I missed that `*static_cast<Derived *>(this)`. Thanks a bunch!